# Click on email addresses to send email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I'd like to rewire Windows' default behavior so that clicking on an email address anywhere (browser, document, etc.) opens in Gmail instead of Outlook. Is that possible? (Windows 7)

Comment: I realize this straddles SuperUser and WebApps - hopefully it's OK to post here.

Comment: It wouldn't get closed on Super User as it's controlling your computer, but it might be OK here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's now installable Google Apps software for Windows - it's really just a wrapper for the web app in Chrome but that registers with Windows as an email client that you can then set as your default just like you would with Outlook or Thunderbird. Works like a charm.

http://pack.google.com/intl/en/pack_installer.html (uncheck the stuff you don't need).

Comment: This link is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

**Control Panel > Internet Options > Programs**

Change "E-mail:" to "Google Mail".

Then whenever you click on a `mailto` link etc. it will open Google Mail instead of Outlook.

Comment: Just as a note to other people reading this: this option isn't available in Windows XP.

Comment: If you install the [GMail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html) it gives you this option in XP too.

Comment: Hmm - that doesn't work for me in Windows 7. Under Control Panel > Internet Options > Programs I only have "Default web browser", "Manage add-ons", "HTML editing", and "Internet programs". The caption for "Internet programs" says "Choose the programs you want tot use for other Internet services such as e-mail"; but the button takes you to the "Default Programs" screen. From there I can go to "Set associations" and edit the MAILTO protocol; but the only options are Outlook and Windows Live Mail.

Comment: @eagle - that's odd as I'm running XP (SP3).

Comment: @ChrisF: do you have the gmail notifier installed, like @pelms mentioned? If so, you should update the answer to mention that it's required.

Comment: @eagle - I don't have the notifier installed. When I rebuilt this machine I installed the Google Pack to get Chrome, SketchUp and Earth installed for all users. In **Start > All Programs > Google Apps** I just have Calender, Docs and Mail.

Comment: @chris: my guess is that the mail app enabled that option

Comment: @eagle - that's even odder - I've never run it - unless it just does it on the install.

Comment: @chris: yeah, it probably added it during the install

Answer (score 1):

A full-featured alternative would be to install [Affixa](http://www.affixa.com) (the free version is fine) - it enables all context menu functionality (Send as attachment, Send to Email Recipient), as well as setting Gmail to your default client. I've used it successfully in XP and W7.

This solution also works with Google Apps and Yahoo! Mail.

Comment: This, I have to try out. Looks interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a browser plugin or userscript to convert [Mailto: links to the format required by Gmail](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/08/27/make-gmail-handle-mailto-links-in-google-chrome/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically Chrome offers an easy way to do this by changing your default email protocol.

**How to set Gmail as your default client in Google Chrome**

1. Open your Google Mail in Chrome.
2. If displayed on the right of the address bar you should see <sub>[image]</sub> symbol. Click on it.

   [image]
3. Select Allow mail.google.com to open all email links. Click Done.

   [image]